# Generate 6 digit alpha numeric value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have the following code; the only issue with it is that sometimes it generates a digit alphanumeric code.

I am trying to modify it such that it always returns a 6 digit code. Any thoughts on how to tweak this?

I have another procedure the purges duplicates and it re-runs, so that is not an issue.

```
SET @HashCode = NULL

SELECT    
    @HashCode = ISNULL(@HashCode, '') + SUBSTRING('23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ', (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 36) + 1, 1)
FROM    
    [master]..[spt_values] AS [spt_values] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE    
    [spt_values].[type] = 'P'
    AND [spt_values].[number] < 6
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the letters that are not to your liking from the `SUBSTRING` and adjusting the `36` accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way of achieving this is selecting the first 6 `LEFT` characters in the string generated by the [NEWID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function:

```
SELECT LEFT(NEWID(), 6)
```

| Examples: |
| --- |
| 4DF32A |
| DC70D5 |
| 8793B2 |
| 3D8416 |
| EE2838 |

**Note**, because the `NEWID()` function generates a unique identifier ([GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)), consisting of hexadecimal characters (A-F & 0-9), there is a chance the output will consist of *only* numbers or *only* letters; which may or may not fit your purpose if you require a strict alphanumeric value.

| Examples: |
| --- |
| 946983 |
| 831814 |
| DDFDBB |

You can use it like this:

```
SET @HashCode = NULL

SELECT    
    @HashCode = LEFT(NEWID(), 6)
```

Comment: Great, thank you.  Makes my select much simpler than it thought!  I will try and report back.  Thank you.

Comment: @Parker any luck?

Comment: Yes, i just had to create a procedure that nulls out the duplicates and continues to run the procedure.  Sorry for the delay in getting back, been some family health problems.

Comment: No worries! I hope things are getting better for you. Hopefully my answer was some help as well.